# How does the XP system work in Agar?

Tags: agar.io

I've been playing Agar for some time now, and lately I've noticed there was a new XP system in Agar. Since then I've been wondering what variables chance the XP gained. I've tried googling it, but with no luck.

I'm looking for how the XP system works in these game modes:

- FFA
- Teams
- Experimental

Comment: Starting size changes (by ~1 per level), any other change would probably influence game balance too much. But I have no source for that and a low sample size.

Comment: No sure answer yet. Only [speculations](https://www.reddit.com/r/Agario/comments/3d1zrh/how_does_the_exp_system_work_for_levels/).

Comment: The same leveling down happened to me also, but after a few refreshing of the page, I got my level back. It must be because of the servers, caching and their location. So all in all we didn't lose xp but the cache hadn't updated quickly enough.

Other than that I did a few test myself and saw that when I feed the spikes I also gain more xp. (probably I get equal amount of xp the points I feed)

Answer (score 6):

The exact method of gaining XP is not known to the public. The current system is **very** unstable and buggy, sometimes getting deleted for no reason. If the method was known to the public, many people would start abusing it, so I don't believe that they will tell us exactly how. It has been noticed, however, that splitting into multiple cells seems to gain you the most XP, as noticed by Reddit user parls (third comment) [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Agario/comments/3d1zrh/how_does_the_exp_system_work_for_levels/). Also, the maximum XP seems to be around 25k.

Comment: This answer is out dated as of more recent versions of the game.

Answer (score 2):

Across all play modes, it seems that XP can be gained quickly by splitting. If you are big enough to split into the maximum of 16 balls, and combine back in to one, you gain greater XP than if you got the #1 spot in free for all.

This is a common team tactic, but keep in mind that teams will lose mass faster from exchanging mass to frequantly.

Keep in mind that the bigger you are when you perform the split, the safer you will potentially be.

Comment: There are some videos of XP accumulation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mEvLdxgicrY  as well as my own experience.  In FFA, my goal was to get to #1 and stay there as long as possible, but the XP did not grow as much as when I changed my tactic/Attitude to splitting, growing, splitting. Try it, you will see.

Answer (score 1):

## This answer is out of date.

<s>The XP system is still being kept secret by the developer, as well as being subject to modifications.</s>

However, a few discoveries have been made:

- You gain XP every second, depending on your mass.
- For a given mass, the more you are split, the more XP you get.
- There is a maximum of 25,000 XP per life.

Comment: @Timelord64 Should I delete it then ?

Comment: a disclaimer that this answer was made out of date as of whatever version should suffice, if you dont feel like updating.

Comment: @Timelord64 Interesting. I found out this post is quoted on [wikia](http://agario.wikia.com/wiki/Levels).

Answer (score 0):

You gain 100 XP every 500 mass.

If you are playing free for all, you also gain 100 bonus XP for staying alive for 30 seconds.

Answer (score -3):

I tested this by eating pallets in that round only. I started that round with 89 744 XP and when I killed myself I had 89 854. I'm not sure if this is correct but this might help test it yourself.

Comment: The max XP is 25k, therefore this answer is unreal.

Comment: @ardaozkal, the reports say the maximum was 25k *per life*. This user reports a mere 110XP gain, which is no where near the maximum, and perfectly plausible. That said, it is quite likely out dated, with more recent versions of the game.